# In Emacs, how can I add a website like 'Stackoverflow' to my webjump hotlist?

Tags: emacs, command

By default the webjump hotlist has the following which I use quite often:

```
M-x webjump RET Google
M-x webjump RET Wikipedia
```

How can I add 'Stackoverflow' to my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example code in [a webjump.el file on a site run by Apple:](http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/10.0/emacs-39/emacs/lisp/webjump.el)

```
;;   (require 'webjump)
;;   (global-set-key "\C-cj" 'webjump)
;;   (setq webjump-sites
;;         (append '(
;;                   ("My Home Page" . "www.someisp.net/users/joebobjr/")
;;                   ("Pop's Site"   . "www.joebob-and-son.com/")
;;                   )
;;                 webjump-sample-sites))
```

Answer (score 2):

A general tip for looking up answers to questions like this one:

1. Look up the help for a relevant function. eg. **C-h f webjump**
2. In the top line of the help buffer, hit RET on the filename in which the function is defined. This will take you to the function definition.
3. **M-<** to jump to the beginning of the buffer.
4. Read through the documentation for the file. Typically (and in this case) this will include information on how to configure the feature.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find where you are setting your `webjump-sites` variable.  This is probably your `.emacs` file.  Then you'll need to add a pair to that alist as follows.

```
("stackoverflow". "www.stackoverflow.com")
```

A full example of what to put in your .emacs would be as follows.

```
(setq webjump-sites
   (append '(("stackoverflow" . "www.stackoverflow.com"))
      webjump-sample-sites)
```